# Why are low band gap semiconductors (like silicon) not ideal for most solar cells? Are their atoms ionized by higher-energy photons?

Tags: solar-cell, optoelectronics, electron, photonics, energy-band

Most sources on the web say that 1.3 eV or 1.4 eV is 'ideal' for most solar cells...

What happens to lower-gap, gapless or overlap materials (conductors)?  Are they ionized, rather than sending their electrons neatly into the conduction band?

P.S.: May I also ask if there are advantages, disadvantages to using 'direct' bandgap semiconductors vs. indirect band gap ones?

Comment: You only get about 0.5V (maybe 0.55V open circuit) from a Si cell. This is the one place where you really want a higher forward voltage in a diode.

Answer (score 2):

See these lecture slides (42 pages) Light Absorption and Thermalization:

http://oasis.mechse.illinois.edu/me432/ME432_L12_Sept21.pdf

Page 15 Thermal Efficiency vs Band Gap

> For small band
> gaps, efficiency is
> limited by
> thermalization
> losses

> For large band
> gaps, efficiency is
> limited by losses
> due to non-
> absorption of the
> solar spectrum

> The tradeoff between thermalization and non-absorption losses results in the optimal band gap of a semiconductor of approximately 1.2 eV, and a maximum theoretical efficiency of close to 30%.

Page 36:

> Light absorption in a direct semiconductor requires only photons

> Light absorption in an indirect semiconductor requires a photon and a phonon, and is statistically less likely to occur.

Page 38:

> Solar cells made from indirect semiconductors need to be thicker
> because we need to provide more opportunities for the transition to take
> place.

Page 39:

> Absorption in indirect semiconductors is temperature-dependent, because phonons are needed and phonon population depends on temperature.

The direct materials may seem to have an advantage, however, the economics and design tradeoff in a given application are not discussed in the reference.